# Can you undo close all Finder windows (alt + click the red close button)?

Tags: finder, macos, shortcut, undo-redo

I just inadvertently closed around 20 Finder windows in one click, each related to ongoing projects in them, by clicking the red window button and having "alt" key pressed.

**Is there something I can do to reopen all the windows that have just been closed?**

It might be too late for me now but if I make this mistake again it will save me a lot of time to reopen these windows.

Comment: As far as Finder, by itself, is concerned, no, once you close them there gone. Have a look at: [Simple WindowSets](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/products/sws/sws.html) BTW I'm not affiliated with HAMSoft Engineering.

Answer (score 2):

This functionality is not available natively in Finder, but it can be gained by the use of third party software such as [XtraFinder](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/) and *perhaps* [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/). Please note though that you would have to check compatibility as you don't specify what version of macOS you're using.

Another option that *may* interest you is to access your *recent folders*. To do this:

- Ensure you have Finder active
- Click on the Go menu
- Hover over the Recent Folders sub-menu
- You'll now see your most recently opened folders
- Select the folders one by one to reopen them

**Notes:**

1. This is not an *undo* option, but at least you can easily reopen most of your Finder windows (although not likely as many as 20 of them).
2. I have no affiliation whatsoever with either [XtraFinder](http://www.trankynam.com/xtrafinder/) or [Default Folder X](http://www.stclairsoft.com/DefaultFolderX/).